# Manipulating data.frame format in BASE R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have seen answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) but I was wondering if in my case there might be an efficient way in BASE R to change my **`input`** data.frame to my desired **`output`** data.frame shown below?

```
input <- data.frame(id = c(1,3,6), school = LETTERS[1:3], read_1 = c(20,22,24),
               read_1_sp = c(T,F,T), read_2 =c(45,47,49),read_2_sp = c(F,F,F),  
               math_1 =c(20,22,NA), math_1_sp = c(T,F,NA), math_2 = c(NA,35,37),
               math_2_sp =c(NA,F,F))


output <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,3),rep(3,4), rep(6, 3)),school = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",4), rep("C", 3)),   
                      subject = c("read","read","math","read","read","math", "math","read","read","math"),  
                      no.= c(1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2), score = c(20,45,20,22,47,22,35,24,49,37),    
                      sp = c(T,F,T,T,F,T,T,T,F,T))
```

Comment: Have you tried `stats::reshape`? It's not the most intuitive to work with, but it does this reshaping you seek.

Comment: Since you're trying to narrow several columns, I suspect it'll be several independent calls to `reshape` and then `merge`ing them together.

Comment: IMO, this is the strong impetus for `tidyr::pivot_longer` ... while I appreciate your incentive to stick with base R, there are reasons convenience functions are such a ... convenience :-)

Comment: Have you considered `sqldf` or some other sql-based solution? It's counter to your base-R constraint, but if you already use one of `sqldf`, `DBI`, `RSQLite`, or some other DBMS elsewhere in your workflow, you can capitalize on using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Base - reshape**  Create a list, `varying`, of two elements each of which is a character vector of names -- the first element is the vector of `score` names and the second is the vector of `sp` names. Use that with base `reshape`. Then sort by the `idvar` variables (or omit the two lines which perform the sorting if this is not required) and remove rows with NAs using `na.omit`. `reshape` produces a `subject` column with entries such as `read_1`. The transform statement splits that into two columns, `subject` and `no`.

```
varying <- lapply(c("\\d$", "sp$"), grep, names(input), value = TRUE)

r <- reshape(input, dir = "long", idvar = c("id", "school"), 
  varying = varying, v.names = c("score", "sp"),
  times = varying[[1]], timevar = "subject")  

o <- with(r, order(id, school))
r <- r[o, ]
r <- na.omit(r)

transform(r, subject = sub("_.*", "", subject), no = as.numeric(sub(".*_", "", subject)))
```

giving:

```
           id school subject score    sp no
1.A.read_1  1      A    read    20  TRUE  1
1.A.read_2  1      A    read    45 FALSE  2
1.A.math_1  1      A    math    20  TRUE  1
3.B.read_1  3      B    read    22 FALSE  1
3.B.read_2  3      B    read    47 FALSE  2
3.B.math_1  3      B    math    22 FALSE  1
3.B.math_2  3      B    math    35 FALSE  2
6.C.read_1  6      C    read    24  TRUE  1
6.C.read_2  6      C    read    49 FALSE  2
6.C.math_2  6      C    math    37 FALSE  2
```

**2) data.table - melt**  The question asked for a base solution but just for comparison we also show a solution using `melt` in data.table.

Convert `input` to a data.table and melt it using the key and the indicated patterns.  `melt` has no counterpart to the `times=` in `reshape` but rather provides index numbers in the `variable.name` column which is `subject` in this case. We use it to index into the `times`.   This produces elements such as `read_1` so we use `fread` to split `subject` into two columns, `subject` and `no`. Finally remove the rows having NAs using `na.omit` and sort by specifying key.

```
library(data.table)

input2 <- as.data.table(input, key = c("id", "school"))
times <- grep("\\d$", names(input2), value = TRUE)  # score col names

melt(input2, measure = patterns(sp = "sp", score = "\\d$"), variable.name = "subject")[, 
  c("subject", "no"):= fread(text = times[subject], sep = "_")][, 
  na.omit(.SD), key = key(input2)]
```

giving:

```
    id school    sp score subject no
 1:  1      A  TRUE    20    read  1
 2:  1      A FALSE    45    read  2
 3:  1      A  TRUE    20    math  1
 4:  3      B FALSE    22    read  1
 5:  3      B FALSE    47    read  2
 6:  3      B FALSE    22    math  1
 7:  3      B FALSE    35    math  2
 8:  6      C  TRUE    24    read  1
 9:  6      C FALSE    49    read  2
10:  6      C FALSE    37    math  2
```

Comment: Have slightly simplified (1) and added (2).

Answer (score 1):

In `tidyverse`, we can do

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
input %>%
   rename_at(vars(matches('\\d+$')), ~ str_c(., '_score')) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(id, school), names_to = c('subject', 'no', '.value'),
          names_sep="_", values_drop_na = TRUE)
# A tibble: 10 x 6
#      id school subject no    score sp   
#   <dbl> <fct>  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <lgl>
# 1     1 A      read    1        20 TRUE 
# 2     1 A      read    2        45 FALSE
# 3     1 A      math    1        20 TRUE 
# 4     3 B      read    1        22 FALSE
# 5     3 B      read    2        47 FALSE
# 6     3 B      math    1        22 FALSE
# 7     3 B      math    2        35 FALSE
# 8     6 C      read    1        24 TRUE 
# 9     6 C      read    2        49 FALSE
#10     6 C      math    2        37 FALSE
```

---

Or an option with `base R`

```
 i1 <-grep("_\\d+$", names(input))
 names(input)[i1] <- paste0(names(input)[i1], "_score")
 lst1 <- lapply(split.default(input[-(1:2)], sub(".*_", "", names(input)[-(1:2)])), function(dat) {
         dat1 <- stack(dat)
          transform(dat1, no = sub("^[^_]+_(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", ind), ind = sub("_.*", "", ind))})
out <- setNames(cbind(lst1[[1]], lst1[[2]][1])[c(2:3, 1, 4)], c('subject', 'no', 'score', 'sp'))
na.omit(cbind(input[rep(seq_len(nrow(input)), each = 4), 1:2], out))
```

Comment: @rnorouzian i added a `base R`

Comment: @rnorouzian i removed that solution as it can gather some dvs.  Anyway, you got another solution that is working in base R

Comment: @Reza I changed the reshape to split as there is already a solution.